# Query custom post types and a specific page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm using this query `WP_Query('post_type=product&posts_per_page=8')` I need to include a specific page into the query but not sure how to add it since I'm only specifying the custom post type? Is it possible to add in a page?

Comment: You need to make 2 queries.

Comment: @Wyck I created a second query which works fine, but isn't there a way to combine this into one and maybe use a do while loop?

Comment: You can query  `'post_type' => array( 'product', 'page')` but then you have to separate the returned data, often it's just easy to do a second query.

Comment: @Wyck I had tried that and used page_id=123 but that didn't seem to filter the pages while leaving the product posts alone.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want a bunch of posts from a custom post type and in some way combine it with a page. To do this you would first have to get the queried objects:

```
$page_id = 123; // the id of the page you want to retrieve
$cpt_objects = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type'        => 'product',
  'posts_per_page'   => 8
  ));
$page_object = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type'        => 'page',
  'page_id'          => $page_id
  ));
```

Now you can loop through the `$cpt_objects` and insert the `$page_object` anywhere you like.